# How to control Apollo upload server multiple stream? like make buffer?

Tags: node.js, stream, apollo, apollo-server

I am trying To upload multiple images for use Apollo server

I succeeded in using the createWriteStream module to convert the stream to a file

but i don't need make file, just need buffer string

But this is not return ever never buffer string

Please see my code

```
type Mutation {
        createProduct(product_name: String!, product_info: String!, price: Int!, sale: Int, files: [Upload!]): Result!
    }
```

this is my Mutation

```
createProduct(parent, {product_name, product_info, price, sale ,files }) {
            db.Product.create({
                product_name, product_info, price, sale
            }).then( (product) => {
                storeImages(files, product.id)    
                .then ( (result) => {
                    console.log(result)
                })
            })
```

and this is my resolver

```
const outStream = new Writable({
    write(chunk, encoding, callback){
        console.log(chunk)
    },
})

const inStream = new Readable({
    read(size) {
        console.log(size)
    }
})

const test2 = (chunk) => {
    console.log(chunk)
    outStream.destroy();
}

function test(){
    let pass = new PassThrough();
    console.log(pass)
    console.log('pass!!')
    return 'end';
}
const processUpload = async upload => {
    const { stream, filename, mimetype } = await upload;
    console.log('stream')
    console.log(upload)
    // const { id, path } = await storeFS({ stream, filename })
    // return storeDB({ id, filename, mimetype, path })
  }


const lastStream = (chunk) => {
    console.log(chunk)
}
const storeImages = (files, product_id) => {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        let save = []
        files.forEach( async (image, index) => {
            const { stream  } = await image;
            stream
                .pipe(outStream)
                // .pipe(inStream)
        })
        resolve(save)
```

Finally, the way I've tried

I'll summarize.

How can I use the apollo upload server to take a stream of multiple files into a blob and control it?